# Java мессенджер клиент-сервер

Tags: java, сокет, messenger

Сделал простеньки мессенджер на джава на сокетах но она работает на локальной сети. Как сделать так чтобы она работала через интернет

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос, на него невозможно ответить содержательно. В чем именно проблема? Что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @m. vokhm в локалке работает по нету нет всё же понятно) нету выделенного ипшника к бабке не ходи)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно "Внешний выделенный постоянный IP-адрес".

Обычно у провайдера докупается за 0.5—1$ в месяц.

Или берете, как выше посоветовали, виртуальный сервер.

Или пробуйте сервисы по типу no-ip.com

Answer (score 2):

Для того, что бы ваш мессенджер заработал через сеть Интернет, его необходимо разместить на каком-то сервере размещенном в сети, например арендовав виртуальный хостинг. Сервер надо будет поднимать с адресом 0.0.0.0, что позволит подключаться к нему по любому сетевому интерфейсу имеющимся на хостинге.
Соответственно адрес сервера надо будет вписать в клиент.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/153586)

Comment: @tCode поправил.